# Optimising match-finding loop for given datasets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have [4 datasets](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F1lLdqpdE-BaBgygjJAm_QfiDfSQymR_?usp=drive_link) for which I have created 3 dataframes and I wanted to do a perfomance evaluation based on the following steps:

> Initial steps
> Take the alerts.csv and create a single column dataframe using source and destination concatenated and remove duplicates
> create a three-column dataframe from cleanips.csv and malips.csv from the domain malicious and ip address columns
> cross check urls in the second dataframe witgh final.csv and add a new column to df2 that has boolean values indicating wheher each urls has a match.
> create a 3rd data frame from final.csvv that takes "Source","Source Address","Destination","Destination Address","Host" and does the following: urls from detination or host are put in a column called url and appended to each other and the corresponding destination address value . remove duplicates in the dataframe
> Create another colum in second dataframe called final ip that prints the final ip addresses which are obtain by the following: if there is a url match that also has an ip match withrd daataframe, the ip address is just copied else, the corresponind IP value from 3rd df  for url
>
> Performance measure:
>
> Use the 2x2 confusion matrix using the following: if there is a match between df1 and final ip in df2 and malicious is true in df2 then it is a true positive. A match and malicious is false is a false positive. No match and malicious is true  is a false negative. If final IP is not in df1 and malicious is false, that is a true negative. For this matrix do not use an array matr5ix but a box matrix that is graphical

I have implemented the steps using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read alerts.csv and create a single-column dataframe
alerts = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Evaluation/Alerts.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'URL': alerts['Src'] + alerts['Dst'], 'IP': alerts['Dst']}).drop_duplicates()

# Read cleanips.csv and malips.csv, concatenate them, and create a three-column dataframe
clean_ips = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Evaluation/CleanIPs.csv')
mal_ips = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Evaluation/malIPs.csv')
df2 = pd.concat([clean_ips[['Domain', 'Malicious', 'IP Address']], mal_ips[['Domain', 'Malicious', 'IP Address']]])

# Read final.csv and create a two-column dataframe, remove duplicates
final = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Evaluation/final.csv')
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'URL': final['Destination'] + final['Host'], 'Address': final['Destination Address']}).drop_duplicates()

# Add a new column to df2 indicating whether each URL has a match in df3
df2['URL Match'] = df2['Domain'].isin(df3['URL'])

# Function to get the final IP address and check IP match
def get_final_ip(row):
    if row['URL Match']:
        if row['IP Address'] in df3[df3['URL'] == row['Domain']]['Address'].values:
            return row['IP Address']
    matches = df3[df3['URL'] == row['Domain']]
    if len(matches) > 0:
        return matches.iloc[0]['Address']
    return ''

# Create the final IP column in df2 using ThreadPoolExecutor
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    final_ips = []
    for _, row in df2.iterrows():
        final_ip = get_final_ip(row)
        final_ips.append(final_ip)

# Assign the final IPs to the dataframe
df2['Final IP'] = final_ips

# Calculate performance measures
true_positive = df2[(df2['Final IP'].isin(df1['IP'])) & (df2['Malicious'] == 'True')].shape[0]
true_negative = df2[(~df2['Final IP'].isin(df1['IP'])) & (df2['Malicious'] == 'False')].shape[0]
false_positive = df2[(df2['Final IP'].isin(df1['IP'])) & (df2['Malicious'] == 'False')].shape[0]
false_negative = df2[(~df2['Final IP'].isin(df1['IP'])) & (df2['Malicious'] == 'True')].shape[0]

# Create a graphical confusion matrix using matplotlib
confusion_matrix = [[true_positive, false_positive], [false_negative, true_negative]]
plt.imshow(confusion_matrix, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks([0, 1], ['Malicious', 'Clean'])
plt.yticks([0, 1], ['Detected', 'Not Detected'])
plt.xlabel('Actual')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.show()

accuracy = ((true_positive + true_negative) / (true_positive + true_negative + false_positive + false_negative)) * 100
print('Accuracy %:', accuracy)
```

The program doess not seem to have errors but colab seems to crash on `def get_final_ip(row)`.

I have tried using dicts and tuples but I get errors and now iterations are giving me problems. Am I missing something or there is another approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your `concurrent.futures` code isn't actually doing anything here.
- `final.csv` is 950mb, you could also host a compressed version.

Instead of `concurrent.futures`, you could use [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/reference/) which will handle parallelism.

It's not entirely clear if you're trying to do a substring/fuzzy match on the Domain/URL or a direct comparison.

Based on your example this is a substring search which ran for me in ~50 seconds:

```
import duckdb

# || is string concat
# if a column can be NULL you can use coalesce(name, '') (like .fillna('') in pandas)
# group by all = unique

out = duckdb.sql("""
with 
   df1 as (
      from 'Alerts.csv'
      select Src || coalesce(Dst, '') URL, Dst IP
      group by all
   ),
   df2 as (
      from read_csv_auto(['CleanIPs.csv', 'malIPs.csv'])
      select Domain, Malicious, "IP Address"
      group by all
   ),
   df3 as (
      from 'final.csv'
      select Destination || coalesce(Host, '') URL, "Destination Address" Address
      group by all
   )
   from df2, df3
   where
      df3.URL.contains(df2.Domain)
""")
```

```
┌────────────┬───────────┬───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│   Domain   │ Malicious │  IP Address   │                          URL                          │     Address     │
│  varchar   │  boolean  │    varchar    │                        varchar                        │     varchar     │
├────────────┼───────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ toremaga.com                                          │ xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx │
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ ieltsidpindia.com                                     │ xx.xxx.xx.xxx   │
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ entripy.comadeccousa.com                              │ xx.xx.xxx.x     │
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ mypaga.com                                            │ xx.xxx.xx.xxx   │
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ zzkorea.comzzkorea.com                                │ xx.xx.xx.xxx    │
│ and.co     │ false     │ xxx.xx.xxx.xx │ fromlongisland.comguitarhabits.com                    │ xxx.xxx.xxx.xx  │
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ tecnologia-tecnica.com.artutorialesprogramacionya.com │ xxx.xx.xxx.xxx  │
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ vogelforvirginia.compolarr.co                         │ xx.xx.xxx.xx    │
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ waerfa.comwaerfa.com                                  │ xx.xxx.xx.xxx   │
│ a.com      │ false     │ NULL          │ mobiledista.comdailyenglish.in.th                     │ xx.xx.xxx.xxx   │
│   ·        │   ·       │  ·            │                ·                                      │      ·          │
│   ·        │   ·       │  ·            │                ·                                      │      ·          │
│   ·        │   ·       │  ·            │                ·                                      │      ·          │
│ gs.com     │ false     │ xxx.xx.xx.xxx │ jovision-usa.comvitasprings.com                       │ xx.x.xxx.xxx    │
│ r.pl       │ false     │ xx.xx.xxx.xx  │ kinder.pl                                             │ xx.xxx.xxx.xx   │
│ te.com     │ false     │ xxx.xxx.xxx.x │ towerunite.comtowerunite.com                          │ xxx.xxx.xxx.x   │
│ foto.ru    │ false     │ xx.xxx.xx.x   │ givefoto.ru                                           │ xx.xxx.xxx.xx   │
│ movies.com │ false     │ xxx.xx.xx.xxx │ apdegreecollegesasni.comcheese-movies.com             │ xx.xx.xx.x      │
│ gs.com     │ false     │ xxx.xx.xx.xxx │ pokerroomkings.com                                    │ xx.xx.xx.xx     │
│ te.com     │ false     │ xxx.xxx.xxx.x │ greenwaste.comgreenwaste.com                          │ xx.xxx.xxx.xx   │
│ te.com     │ false     │ xxx.xxx.xxx.x │ egyptadmissions.comrx-karte.com.de                    │ xx.x.x.xxx      │
│ r.pl       │ false     │ xx.xx.xxx.xx  │ lkw-walter.atlkw-walter.pl                            │ xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx │
│ gs.com     │ false     │ xxx.xx.xx.xxx │ kata-bags.comentrevistasdetrabajo.com                 │ xxx.xx.xxx.xx   │
├────────────┴───────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┤
│ ? rows (>9999 rows, 20 shown)                                                                          5 columns │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

You could also implement the IP counting in SQL, or do it in pandas.

You can `.df()` to convert back to a pandas dataframe.

https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/export_pandas